# How to make computations with Google Cloud?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a machine learning project and for this project, I have to get data from a website in evey 15 minutes. And I decided to use google cloud platform to do it. I've coded a python script to do the process(get the data from website and write down to a csv file) and when I run this script on my computer, it works well. I need to run this script for a couple weeks. So it should be running in google cloud's computers and it should continue running when I close my computer. How can I do this?

I can also use another cloud service if it's required to but google cloud would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm with Google Cloud Platform Support

[Google Cloud Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) is defined as an Infrastructure as a Service. It basically provides access to Virtual Machines (VMs), Disks and Networking functionalities. By using this product, you are able to configure your resources from scratch, defining one or multiple VM instances, configuring your work environment, etc. It might require more configuration and *boiler plating* than needed, but it offers the most control. You can always use some resources [for free](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#freeusage) but in my opinion it is a lot of scratch to start from.

[Google Cloud App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) is defined as a Platform as a Service. It is basically a managed app platform. The management can be automatised to certain degrees. It is based on Compute Engine, in the sense that it provides functionalities, a platform, on top of the infrastructure defined by Compute Engine VMs. You can thus deploy your python script in an [App Engine Flexible Python Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/). You can define your whole application as a collection of interrelated [microservices](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/an-overview-of-app-engine), i.e. one service gets the data from a website, maybe another writes csv files and another might trigger ML jobs.
App Engine also provides the possibility to [schedule jobs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml) as cron jobs. So if your application needs to run periodical jobs or at a specific time, this is the tool to use. App Engine [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing) is correlated with the used resources, but you can estimate eventual budgets by using the [Google Cloud Platform Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/#tab=app-engine).

You can store the csv files in [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) as objects in [buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/how-to) or as data in [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/), [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/) or [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/). Components of Google Cloud Platform can communicate with each other via [service acounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts). This allows your App Engine deployment, for example, to perform CRUD operations in your Cloud SQL instance, programatically. Or... to trigger a [Cloud Machine Learning job](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/).

Your question is **very** broad and can be addressed in multiple, various ways. I would initially [deploy](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart#deploy_and_run_hello_world_on_app_engine) the python script in App Engine Flexible. I would [deploy a cron job](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#uploading_cron_jobs) if needed, to fetch data every 15 minutes. I would [upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics#storage-upload-object-python) the csv files in Google Cloud Storage Buckets. I would then use the Cloud Machine Learning [python client](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/python-guide) to trigger Machine Learning jobs programatically.

There are other products that might interest you:

- [Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/python-guide) - configure stream/batch data processing
- [Cloud Dataprerp](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/) - transform/clean raw data
- [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/) - global real-time messaging.

All the products/components and sub-products/sub-components can communicate with each other and processes can easily be automated in the Cloud. So the whole project can run in Google's Cloud infrastructure *when you close your computer*. But, of course, you have to configure it beforehand, in your [Google Cloud Platform Project(s)](https://console.cloud.google.com).

I am aware that I met your broad question with a broad answer. For any specific issues along your path of implementing the project in the Cloud, the community will be here to provide support.

Good luck!

Comment: I have this startup script:     `#! /bin/bash
apt-get update
apt-get install -y python3-pip
pip3 install coinmarketcap
gsutil cp gs://cryptocurrency-data-storage/startup.py /home/burkaykirnik/startup.py
python3 startup.py`. It installs required api, downloads the code but doesn't run the code. The last line doesn't work. What's the problem? If I connect to instance with SSH, I can run it with the last line but it doesn't continue running when I close the terminal.  And here is startup.py: [link](https://github.com/BurkayKirnik/Automatic-Crypto-Currency-Data-Getter/blob/master/code.py)

Comment: hi @AhmetBurkayKırnık!

Since this comment is first of all a question in itself and it is not clearly related neither with my answer, nor with your original post, I suggest you create a new StackOverflow question from this specific comment. This way, it will benefit the entire community, being easier to find. 

If I answer your comment through another comment, both the question and the answer will be hidden under this question's topic.. which is not fair. I suggest you create a new question and then paste the link as a comment here so that I can access (and hopefully answer) it.